# If statement not changing initialized value

Tags: java, if-statement

My enum type is not being changed from its default "null" value when displayed by a basic toString method. When the user inputs JPG,GIF, etc the if statement is supposed to recognize that the inputted string corresponds to enum. Why is the if statement not  taking the user's input and converting it to match the enum?

```
public static void processPhotos()
{
    String value;
    String size;
    String name;
    String strType;
    double dSize;
    String photographer;
    int iValue = 1;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);


    while(iValue>0)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the Photo's name.");
        name = kb.nextLine();
        System.out.print ("\nEnter the Photo's type(JPG, GIF, PNG, BMP, or OTHER).");
        strType = kb.nextLine();
        strType = strType.toUpperCase ( );
        if(strType == "JPG")
        {
            type = Type.JPG;
        }
        if(strType == "GIF")
        {
            type = Type.GIF;
        }
        if(strType == "PNG")
        {
            type = Type.PNG;
        }
        if(strType == "BMP")
        {
            type = Type.BMP;
        }
        if(strType == "OTHER")
        {
            type = Type.OTHER;
        }

        System.out.print("\nEnter the Photo's size(IN Megabytes)");
        size = kb.nextLine();
        dSize = Double.parseDouble (size);
        System.out.print("\nEnter the Photo's Photographer");
        photographer = kb.nextLine();
        Photo p = new Photo(name,type,dSize,photographer);
        System.out.print (p.toString());
        System.out.print("\n\nEnter an integer greater than zero to continue. Enter ZERO to end.");
        value = kb.nextLine();
        iValue = Integer.parseInt(value);

    }
}
```

Comment: When a programmer compares string's with == , SO cries.

Comment: let me google for you : http://bit.ly/1juJYH0

Comment: lol..@MustafaGenç..let me google for you..;)

Comment: @user2909717 if my answer is helpful then you select my answer

Answer (score 1):

Compare the strings with this approach instead.

```
if(strType.equals("JPG"))
```

Then you compare the two strings for having the same value.

The == compare that the two strings are in fact the same object stored in memory, of which they are not.

Answer (score 0):

`if(strType == "JPG")`

it should be :

```
if(strType.equalsIgnoreCase( "JPG"))
```

so for every `==` change it to `equalsIgnoreCase` or `equals`

Comment: Yap as String is object

Answer (score 0):

You have to use equals instead of ==

```
type == Type.JPG // comparing references
Type.JPG.equals(type) //Compares valus
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare strings you need to use`.equals` instead of `==`
So your code should be `if(strType.equals("JPG"))`

```
public static void processPhotos()
{
    String value;
    String size;
    String name;
    String strType;
    double dSize;
    String photographer;
    int iValue = 1;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);


    while(iValue>0)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the Photo's name.");
        name = kb.nextLine();
        System.out.print ("\nEnter the Photo's type(JPG, GIF, PNG, BMP, or OTHER).");
        strType = kb.nextLine();
        strType = strType.toUpperCase ( );
        if(strType.equas("JPG"))
        {
            type = Type.JPG;
        }
        if(strType.equals("GIF")).
        {
            type = Type.GIF;
        }
        if(strType.equals("PNG"))
        {
            type = Type.PNG;
        }
        if(strType.equals("BMP"))
        {
            type = Type.BMP;
        }
        if(strType.equals("OTHER"))
        {
            type = Type.OTHER;
        }

        System.out.print("\nEnter the Photo's size(IN Megabytes)");
        size = kb.nextLine();
        dSize = Double.parseDouble (size);
        System.out.print("\nEnter the Photo's Photographer");
        photographer = kb.nextLine();
        Photo p = new Photo(name,type,dSize,photographer);
        System.out.print (p.toString());
        System.out.print("\n\nEnter an integer greater than zero to continue. Enter ZERO to end.");
        value = kb.nextLine();
        iValue = Integer.parseInt(value);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a switch case/condition check for this , you can convert your user input to enum as follows:

```
enum Type {
        JPG, GIF, PNG;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String input = "GIF";
        Type type = Type.valueOf(input);
        System.out.println(type);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use equals instead. Here is a thread discussing why you should do that.

- [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

briefly

`== tests` for reference equality.

`.equals()` tests for value equality.

Answer (score 0):

override equals() method of Object class while comparing two string .

ex : str1.equals(str2);

Comment: Why you want to override equals() method of Object class? equals() method is already been overriden by String class for String comparison. You just have to invoke it on a string object

Answer (score -1):

Make your live easier and Parse the Enum. You won't have to write that much code and if the enum changes, you don't have to change the method. Also you can choose a default Type of your choise or do anything else if strType is not a Type in the Enum.

```
if (Enum.TryParse<Type>(strType, out type))
    type = Type.OTHER
```